# Div to resize as per the span within the div

Tags: html, css

I have a span inside a div tag as below

```
<div class="Panel">
<span class="spanClass">
This is a test </br> break added <br> second break
</span>
</div>

 .Panel {
    font-size: .7em;
    color: Black;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  min-width:200px
  width:auto;
  }

  .spanClass
  {
    background-color: red;
    width:auto;
  }
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/2k0rq3q0/4/

I want the div to resize as per the text in the span and not take the width as of the parent. Is this possible?
I can set the max-width:200px; but I want it to resize as per text.

Also, If there is no text in span, is it possible to not display div? Right now and empty box is shown

Comment: `display:inline-block` on the .`Panel` should do it...[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw2zpy4v/)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `.Panel` to have a `display:inline-block` shrinks it down to the its contents.  You still have padding that makes it a bit wider than the content, but you can remove that as well.  Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hw2zpy4v/).

```
.Panel {
    font-size: .7em;
    color: Black;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    //padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px; <- remove the padding if you truly want it flush
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    // vertical-align: middle; <- not needed, it's for inline elements and table cells
    // height: auto; <- not really needed, unless it's inheriting a height elsewhere
    text-align: left;
    min-width:200px
    // width:auto; <- not really needed, unless it's inheriting a width elsewhere
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it works.
If there is no text in span, is it possible to not display div? Right now and empty box is shown.

Comment: @perplexDev Dropping the min-width would collapse the div, but you'll still have the border visible at that point.  You could toggle a class with JS to add/remove the border as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below example. By just adding display: inline-block; will fix your issue

```css
 .Panel {
 font-size: .7em;
 color: Black;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
 padding: 5px 50px 5px 50px;
 border: solid 1px black;
 background-color: yellow;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: auto;
  text-align: left;
  min-width:100px;
  width:auto;
  display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .spanClass
  {
    background-color: red;
    width:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="Panel">
<span class="spanClass">
This is a test test test test test test test test test test </br> break added <br> second break
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, it works as expected. If there is no text in span, is it possible to not display div? Right now and empty box is shown.

Answer (score 0):

use override

```
<div class="Panel panel2">
<span class="spanClass ">
This is a test test test test test test test test test test </br> break added <br> second break
</span>
</div>
```

for css

```
 .panel2{
        font-size: 2em !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Panel').width($('.spanClass').width()); 
});
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/w5f1bnat/)